# Есть ли в Skype Web API для отправки сообщений?

Tags: api, skype

Есть ли в Skype Web API для отправки сообщений?

Нужно для отправки сообщений пользователю, после срабатывания определенных событий на сайте

Comment: Посмотрите в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962123(v=office.16).aspx), я так понимаю Вас интересует ChatService.

Comment: @AlexKrass А вы работали с их API? Так же не могу найти подключение библиотеки

Comment: Нет, не работал, но как правила вся необходимая информация по возможностям есть в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt124991.aspx). В том числе и [подключение библиотеки](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt150216(v=office.16).aspx), даже с некоторыми [примерами](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn962162(v=office.16).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub button1_click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        AxSkype1.SendMessage(TextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Text)
        RichTextBox1.Text = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?